# Python WSGI missing request header 'If-None-Matches'

Tags: python, http, header, wsgi

I'm using Python & WSGI to create a web application.
Currently I'm loading the server with wsgiref.simple_server.make_server .
However, I'm running into the problem that not all request headers are given to my application. Specifically the header "If-None_matches".
The browser is sending it, but I don't get an environment variable like "HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCHES" for some reason. Anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so the problem is, the header is called "If-None-Match", which is not plural.